# AsyncSocket can connect to java Socket server but can't write data

Tags: java, iphone, sockets, asyncsocket

every time i call upLoad, Java console prints accept, but nothing else, is the data transfered?

I changed the writedata call to didConnectToHost, and now the client say that the data has been transfered, but how can I show these data in Java Server console?

this is my java server code:

```
import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*; 

public class Server 
{ 
    private ServerSocket ss; 
    private Socket socket; 
    private BufferedReader in; 
    private PrintWriter out; 

    public Server() 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            ss = new ServerSocket(8080); 

            while (true) 
            { 
                socket = ss.accept(); 
                System.out.println("accepted");
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); 
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true); 

                String line = in.readLine(); 
                out.println("you input is :" + line); 
                out.close(); 
                in.close(); 
                socket.close(); 
            } 
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {} 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        new Server(); 
    } 
}
```

this is my iPhone Client code:

```
-(IBAction)upLoad{
    NSError* error;
    NSString* hostIP = @"127.0.0.1";
    UInt16 port = 8080;
    [aSocket connectToHost:hostIP onPort:port withTimeout:-1 error:&error];

    NSData *dataToUpload = [@"testxyz" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark socketdelegate
- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port
{   
    connectionStatus.text = @"connected to server!";
    NSData *dataToUpload = [@"testxyz" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   [sock writeData:dataToUpload withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
}

- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didWriteDataWithTag:(long)tag
{
    connectionStatus.text = @"write complete!";
}
```

Comment: I suggest you print out your exceptions rather than ignore them, esp when you have issue to solve. As Brian suggests it doesn't appear to be a problem on the Java side. BTW: If you are sending UTF-8, you should try to read with the same encoding.

Comment: Your server will only accept one connection at a time. This shouldn't effect your testing.

Comment: I actually misread the code the first time. There's a perfectly good reason he doesn't see anything else on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're not outputting anything else to the console. You're sending it back to the client:

```
out.println("you input is :" + line);
```

If you telnet to your server and type something, you'll see you get back what you typed.

I think you're looking for:

```
System.out.println("you input is :" + line);
```

Comment: this is it! the server code was not written by me so I took it for granted that it will print what I send to it.

Comment: I think it was just an easy typo to make, since the client output stream was named 'out'. I even missed it the first time I read over it.